# Error when attempting to import sklearn in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am running into an error that reads

```
cannot import name '__check_build' from partially initialized module 'sklearn' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

when I attempt to import sklearn. I have tried running

```
pip uninstall sklearn
pip install scipy
pip install sklearn
```

as I have seen in other posts, to no avail. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart the shell? If not, try doing it.

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8754 maybe? it's old but has a ton of pointers

Comment: where is code which imports it? What is name of file? Maybe problem makes only your code, not modules - and reinstalling modules can't resolve problem.